# select the inverse of sql result as a string list

Tags: select, oracle10g, inversion

having a sql e.g. something like the following resulting in some rows with one value.
I search a different sql than SELECT * FROM some_sql which results in one row with comma separated values.

```
WITH some_sql AS (
  SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 2 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT * FROM some_sql
```

this SQL results in the two rows with value 1 and 2.
I seach a SQl resulting in 1,2 without changing the code of 'some_sql'.

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate the values taken from multiple rows into a single string, and the number of rows is not known in advance?

Comment: Yes. I expect any number of rows up to about 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider http://halisway.blogspot.com/2006/08/oracle-groupconcat-updated-again.html

Answer (score 2):

Sice you are on 11G you can use [LISTAGG](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions087.htm)

```
WITH some_sql AS (
  SELECT 1 x FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 2 x FROM DUAL
)
SELECT LISTAGG(x, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY x) FROM some_sql
```

Comment: +2 very good answer, only I just realized it's 10g DB with 11g Driver ;-(